# How to serve responsive images using srcset in a v-for loop with Vue.JS?

Tags: responsive-design, vue.js, vuejs2, responsive-images

```
        <div class="image-thumbnail--hero">
           <img  :src="project.thumbnails.small[0]" 
                 :srcset="`${project.thumbnails.small[0]} 300w, ${project.thumbnails.medium[0]} 900w, ${project.thumbnails.high[0]} 1400w`"
                 sizes="(min-width: 768px) 70vw, (min-width: 1200px) 50vw, 300px" 
                 width="100%"
                 :alt="project.title">
        </div>
        <div class="image-thumbnails">
          <ul class="list-unstyled">
            <li v-for="thumbnail in project.thumbnails.small" @click="swapThumbnail(thumbnail)">
              <img class="lazy" :data-src-lazy="thumbnail" alt="thumbnail" width="100">
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
```

Suppose I have these thumbnail images, different resolutions for different viewports.

```
         thumbnails: {
            small: [
              'http://placehold.it/330x330',
              'http://placehold.it/330x330',
              'http://placehold.it/330x330'
            ],
            medium: [
              'http://placehold.it/900x900',
              'http://placehold.it/900x900',
              'http://placehold.it/900x900'
            ], 
            high: [
              'http://placehold.it/1400x1400',
              'http://placehold.it/1400x1400',
              'http://placehold.it/1400x1400'
            ]
          },
```

I want to loop set a set of images, and they should be responsive using srcset attribute. Right now I just loop through the small thumbnails:

```
        <div class="image-thumbnails">
          <ul class="list-unstyled">
            <li v-for="thumbnail in project.thumbnails.small" @click="swapThumbnail(thumbnail)">
              <img class="lazy" :data-src-lazy="thumbnail" alt="thumbnail" width="100">
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
```

Is there a way to make it responsive? Just like the code inside `image-thumbnail--hero`?

The thumbnails inside `image-thumbnails` are small, like 100x100. When a user clicks one of the thumbnails, a higher resolution is shown in `image-thumbnail--hero`. When I didn't use responsive images, I had defined a method for doing this:

```
swapThumbnail(imgUrl) {
    this.selectedThumbnail = imgUrl;
  }
```

`selectedThumbnail` is supposed to bind to `image-thumbnail--hero img`, but since that part is now using responsive image, it's hard to make it work because I don't know which resolution of the image (small, medium, high) should I select and show.

To sum up, there are the 2 problems I find difficult to solve

- show responsive images with v-for
- show a high resolution image (hero image) when a user clicks the associated thumbnail.

The hero image and thumbnail images should both be responsive.

Any insight would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Couldn't you just pass in the index value from v-for into: `:srcset="`${project.thumbnails.small[index]} 300w, ${project.thumbnails.medium[index]} 900w, ${project.thumbnails.high[index]} 1400w`"` instead of hard-coding the value?